# Graph showing proximity of two objects over time

Tags: proximity

I have a dataset showing time and location data for two moving objects (eg B & D). I want to make a graph which shows how close (difference between LAT/LON) two objects (B & D) have been during their travel over a period of time (3 months). I am a noob but am willing to learn. How I can I make this graph? What tools would I need for this?

[image: Example data is]

Comment: In what space do you want them to be 'closed'? Along the Earth surface, in a 2D Cartesian space, or in a 3D Cartesian space?

Comment: What software do you want to do this with? Or do you want the mathematics?

Comment: You seem to have several problems here, including tool selection, tool use, and data presentation. None of these are particularly difficult, but in combination make for an *unclear* and *unfocused* Question. If you choose a tool capable of solving the Inverse (aka Reverse) Problem of Geodesy, and try to use it to compute distances, then you'll be in a better position to ask a question if you run into difficulty.